# How to implement generic interface IEnumerable for 2 different types?

Tags: generics, c++-cli

I have to implement IEnumerable interface for 2 different types in C++/CLI?

`IEnumerable<PmaIf::ICounterValue^>^`

`IEnumerator<System::String^>^`

If i try to implement GetEnumerator for these 2 types, i get error saying method cannot be overloaded with only distinguished return type.

Comment: Please post your code? My crystal ball is still in repair.

Comment: How would the result work in practice? I enumerate your class and get what? Will I always have to explicitly cast it?

Comment: This is not `c++`; should not be tagged that way.

Comment: virtual System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerator<System::String^>^ GetEnumerator() = System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerable<System::String^> :: GetEnumerator

Comment: virtual System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerator<PmaIf::ICounter^>^ GetEnumerator() = System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerable<PmaIf::ICounter^> ::GetEnumerator

Answer (score 1):

You can't have your class have two different public `GetEnumerator`. What you'll need to do is to use explicit interface implementation. With explicit interface implementation, the methods will have different names in your class, but each will implement `GetEnumerator` for one of the two interfaces.

Here is the syntax:

```
public ref class PmaThing : public IEnumerable<PmaIf::ICounterValue^>, IEnumerable<System::String^>
{
public:
    virtual IEnumerator<PmaIf::ICounterValue^>^ GetCounterEnumerator() sealed = 
            IEnumerable<PmaIf::ICounterValue^>::GetEnumerator;

    virtual IEnumerator<System::String^>^ GetStringEnumerator() sealed = 
            IEnumerable<System::String^>::GetEnumerator;
}
```

<sub>Note: I didn't check my syntax with a compiler, but my recollection is that both `virtual` and `sealed` are required when doing explicit interface implementations.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I'm not going to comment on whether or not doing this is a good idea or not, I'm going to give you the syntax to do it.  The example below will generally act as an IEnumerable of int.  If cast to IEnumerable of double it will use the double enumerator.  If your class implements the IEnumerable of T interface for two different T's, one of them is going to have to be explicitly implemented, meaning that implementation is only accessible when accessing through the interface.

The following is the header file:

```
using namespace System;

namespace DoubleEnumerableTest 
{
    public ref class EnumerableAsIntAndDouble : 
        System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerable<int>, 
        System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerable<double>
    {
    public:
        //the class by default (when not cast to IEnumerable<double>) will 
        //use this enumerator
        virtual System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerator<int>^ GetEnumerator() sealed;
    private:
        //non generic enumerator will be of integers
        virtual System::Collections::IEnumerator^ GetNonGenericEnumerator() 
           sealed = System::Collections::IEnumerable::GetEnumerator;

        //Only accessible when cast to IEnumerable<double>
        virtual System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerator<double>^ 
          GetDoubleEnumerator() sealed = 
             System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerable<double>::GetEnumerator;
    };
}
```

The following goes in the implementation file (along with the code that actually creates the enumerators you want):

```
System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerator<int>^ 
    DoubleEnumerableTest::EnumerableAsIntAndDouble::GetEnumerator()
{
    // Create enumerator for type int here
    throw gcnew System::NotImplementedException();

}

System::Collections::IEnumerator^ 
    DoubleEnumerableTest::EnumerableAsIntAndDouble::GetNonGenericEnumerator()
{
    //non-generic enumerator delegates to integer enumerator
    return GetEnumerator();
}

System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerator<double>^ 
     DoubleEnumerableTest::EnumerableAsIntAndDouble::GetDoubleEnumerator()
{
    //Create enumerator for type double in here
    throw gcnew System::NotImplementedException();
}
```